# How can I increase a number by 1 on a text(link) and create new texts with actual number but +1 every copy

Tags: excel, excel-formula, numbers, notepad++

hope my title didin't made to big confusions but here is the thing :

```
https://asds.asddsa.com/test/testT/testTT/1227/3122222469_asd.com
```

I have this link in notepad++, see this number? "3122222469"
how can I generate that link with everything the same as it its but this number "3122222469" to be increase by 1, like this "3122222470" , "3122222471" until 100, more or less.

Comment: This is not a job for Notepad++. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: yes toto, I know I'm trying in excel how Wizhi recomended me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have done something like this in excel:

```
="https://asds.asddsa.com/test/testT/testTT/1227/"&$A$1 + B1 &"_asd.com"
```

[image]

---

If you only want one dummy cell you could in `B1`: ="3122222469" in `B2`:`=B1+1`
And use the same formula in `C1` as above.